# try to hide last column fail with error "Cannot shift objects off sheet"

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

So for some purpose, I need to insert a comment in the last column of excel.

Since I don't want user to be able to see the comment I inserted, I try to hide the column.

Somehow it gave me an error "Cannot shift objects off sheet"

Constants.cs

```
HIDDEN_DATA_COL =  16384; // Which is last column in excel 2007
```

MyUtil.cs

```
Excel.Range range = ws.get_Range(ws.Cells[1, Constants.HIDDEN_DATA_COL], ws.Cells[1, Constants.HIDDEN_DATA_COL]);
 range.AddComment(result);
 range.Comment.Shape.Width = 50;
 range.Comment.Shape.Height = 50;
 range.EntireColumn.Hidden = true;
```

I also make some trial :

- remove range.EntireColumn.Hidden and the code is OK.
- changing the HIDDEN_DATA_COL to number less than 10 its also make the runtime error dissapear.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Hiding*" comments in the last column of the sheet is **probably not the best way to solve your original issue**.

You faced the issue of the Cannot shift objects off sheet error within your code but even if you managed to do it, your user would face it whenever he or she would try to hide or insert any column.

Here is how Microsoft advice to handle this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211769

---

As this might be a case of an [XY issue](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341), I will suggest some workarounds.

Actually, in your case, you'd probably ***hide* your comment somewhere else**, in any hidden cell for instance and if you want the user not to see it, just protect your sheet from unhiding cells.

If you don't want to protect, you can store your comments in another sheet and hide it with VBA using the `xlVeryHidden property` (user cannot unhide the sheet without VBA).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by selecting the comment column first.

```
 range.AddComment(result);
 range.Comment.Shape.Width = 50;
 range.Comment.Shape.Height = 50;
 range.Columns.Cells.Select();
 range.Columns.EntireColumn.Select();
 range.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not just to hide a column but also to reduce the width of a column, the same error gets presented. To fix= Take the comment information, post/paste it in a different cell to save. Then delete the comment, adjust the column and create the comment again for the cell you had it in before. Do this for each comment on the desired sheet.
Hope this helps, Enjoy. BigEEE :)